# Custom triangle using Canvas, want to place this view in List row

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have created a custom triangle using canvas, I created a class which is as follows:

```
@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
public class GameView extends View {
    private Bitmap bmp;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.days2);
    }
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);


        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);

        Point a = new Point(0, 0);
        Point b = new Point(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);
        Point c = new Point(canvas.getWidth(),0);



        Path path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
        path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
        path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        canvas.rotate(36);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(50);
        canvas.drawText("Vertical 45 degree text", (canvas.getHeight()/2)-30 ,0-30 , paint);

    }
}
```

I want to apply this shape to a listview row, however when I place a view in XML which refers to this class. It takes up my whole layout height. Which I dont want. If i specify a height in dp, the view gets clipped. How to overcome this?

Please dont mind the obect allocation in the onDraw, I will remove this and optimize once I get the thing going.

Comment: Maybe you can share your xml file of ListView.

Comment: I solved this problem, It was my mistake in drawing the triangle, I had to use  `Point c = new Point(canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()/2);` instead of ` Point c = new Point(canvas.getWidth(),0);` This resulted in point C being all the way through x and mid way through y :)